# core location constants meaning

Tags: ios, gps, wifi, core-location

I am very confused about the meaning of the core location constants. For example for my app I would like to get accuracy readings within 100 meters and it looks like `kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters` would be the appropriate choice. However with this settings I often get points with accuracy worse than +- *one thousand* meters and when I disable wifi. Are these core location constants only relevant when wifi is enabled or does it sound like I am doing something wrong? It seems weird that Apple wants developers to not have to worry about the underlying hardware (i.e. whether it is using gps, wifi, or cell towers) but have the accuracy totally depend on wifi being enabled.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

GPS readings depend on a LOT more than just your accuracy setting. For example if you are not using wifi and you try to take a reading from indoors I have seen GPS be several thousand meters off consistently until you go outside. If you are planning on making your app accurate for indoors I would not plan on relying on the typical GPS. If your major use case is outside than GPS is VERY accurate.

Comment: well if I am using `kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters` outdoors and GPS is available will it use GPS if wifi is disabled? What I have seen in my app is that it doesn't use GPS and instead gives wildly inaccurate cell tower values. Does this seem like I am doing something wrong or is this to be expected?

Comment: When I was testing with the hundred meter settings, and I was outdoors, I would always get really good readings. I am assuming you called startUpdatingLocation and not startMonitoringForSignificant changes or something else. If so, then I am not sure what the problem could be perhaps the hardware your using is different than the 4s I did most of my testing on

Comment: I've tested on a 4,4s and 5. For all devices it seems that for `kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters` when wifi is disabled in settings the accuracy I get is really bad (over +-1000 meters). When wifi is enabled and an access point is available I get better accuracy (around +-65 meters). This seems to imply that GPS is not used for `kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters`. This doesn't sound right since I believe the device should use whatever hardware it can to get within 100 meter accuracy.

Comment: Yikes. Im probably mistaken then. I think I may have commented on your other post about the distance filter and battery conservation. I think a similar approach might be taken here. I have found with GPS that it pays to put it on the most accurate setting and only check when you absolutely need to or at intervals. If your making an app that has to actively track the user in the foreground it is probably best to just have it on the best setting. Kinda lame but yeah

Answer (score 0):

The accuracy constants are how you "request" a specific accuracy.  What you actually get depends on what is available.  CL will try to give you your requested accuracy (or better) but it will give you what it has even if it is worse accuracy while it is trying to get better accuracy location.

If you wait long enough (and ignore the locations that aren't good enough) then you will eventually get better accuracy location unless it can't be done (such as when GPS satellites aren't visible or there is no WiFi, etc).

Comment: have you tried using kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters with wifi disabled? In my app it only returns values with greater than +-1000 meters. This is outside in a city and I have tested this at walking and driving speeds. Thanks for your help